How do I filter out Indian posts on LinkedIn?
How do I filter out Indian posts? I like to see posts related to my search but filter out those from India.

Welcome to Web Applications. Consider registering your account to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. Registering is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see Why should I register my account?
